# How to convert an NHibernate.Expression.Order object into a string?

Tags: nhibernate, icriteria

I have a list of NHibernate.Expression.Order objects and want to convert them into a sql string.

i.e. "Name ASC, Id DESC, Amount ASC"

Comment: Why would do you need to do that? Isn't the purpose of hibernate to *not* write sql? If you want to write you own query, you can use Expression.Sql() or if you want to see the SQL generated you can run you code with showsql option set or use hibernate statistics.

Comment: the problem is the ignoring of the principle of "persistence of ignorance" in the UI. I use NHibernate + ADO.NET. and I want to change as less as possible in the UI. So only want to transform a List of Order objects into a sql string. But it seems I have a quick solution for that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<string> sqlSortingList = new List<string>();
                    if (OrderList != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Order order in OrderList)
                        {
                            sqlSortingList.Add(order.ToString());
                        }
                    }
```

Later I will concatenate the strings into one string.